# React redux, each child component is getting the same value from redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a parent component that maps out a list of child component. Each child component has their own props like name, id, etc. I want to persist the checkbox is checked value on page refresh so I am using redux for storage. When I check/uncheck an individual checkbox, all the others checkboxes also gets checked/unchecked.

component file

```
const Daily = ({ daily, character_id }) => {
  const { dailyName, id } = daily;
  const checkbox = useSelector(checkboxSelector)
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  const deleteDaily = async (id) => {
    const dailyDoc = doc(db, `charactersDailies/${character_id}/dailies`, id)
    await deleteDoc(dailyDoc)
    window.location.reload(false)
  }

  return (
    <div className="dailyContainer">
      <input
        className="dailyCheckbox"
        id={daily.id}
        type="checkbox"
        checked={checkbox}
        onChange={() => dispatch(setCheckboxAction(daily.id))}
      />            
      <label className="dailyName" htmlFor={daily.id}>
        <h4 className="dailyName">{dailyName.toUpperCase()}</h4>
      </label>
      <h4 className="deleteDailyBTN" onClick={() => deleteDaily(id)}>
        &#10005;
      </h4>
    </div>
  )
};

export default Daily;
```

redux action file

```
export const setCheckboxAction = (id) => {
  return {
    type: 'SET-CHECKBOX',
    payload: id
  }
};
```

redux reducer file

```
const checkboxReducer = (state = null, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'SET-CHECKBOX':
      return !state

    default:
      return state
  }
};

export default checkboxReducer;
```

How do I only access each individual checkbox state from redux instead of all of the checkboxes?

Comment: Drew Reese already answered your question, but I want to add two things: for one, that checkbox state might not even be global state. If you just want state per component, please use local component starte and always evaluate what you put into global application state. Second, and more important: you are writing an extremely outdated style of Redux here - modern Redux is very different and only 1/4 of the code. Please read [this page abount modern Redux](https://redux.js.org/introduction/why-rtk-is-redux-today) in the official Redux documentation

Comment: @phry, thanks for the tip. I just converted some old redux functions into the newer method using the toolkit, it was very helpful and easier to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issue

All the checkboxes are using the same single checked state since it's a boolean.

```
export const setCheckboxAction = (id) => {
  return {
    type: 'SET-CHECKBOX',
    payload: id
  }
};
```

```
const checkboxReducer = (state = null, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'SET-CHECKBOX':
      return !state // <-- single boolean state
    default:
      return state
  }
};
```

```
const Daily = ({ daily, character_id }) => {
  ...

  const checkbox = useSelector(checkboxSelector); // <-- single state

  ...

  return (
    <div className="dailyContainer">
      <input
        ...
        checked={checkbox} // <-- single state
        ...
      />            
      ...
    </div>
  )
};
```

## Solution

Use the passed `id` payload of the `setCheckboxAction` action to conditionally toggle a specific checkbox *by id*. Convert the `checkbox` state to an object/map that uses the passed `id` as a computed property and toggles the truthy/falsey value. The UI will check the value using `daily.id`.

Example:

```
const checkboxReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'SET-CHECKBOX':
      return {
        ...state,
        [action.payload]: !state[action.payload], // payload -> id
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

```
const Daily = ({ daily, character_id }) => {
  const { dailyName, id } = daily;
  const checkboxes = useSelector(checkboxSelector);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const deleteDaily = async (id) => {
    const dailyDoc = doc(db, `charactersDailies/${character_id}/dailies`, id)
    await deleteDoc(dailyDoc)
    window.location.reload(false)
  }

  return (
    <div className="dailyContainer">
      <input
        className="dailyCheckbox"
        id={daily.id}
        type="checkbox"
        checked={checkboxes[daily.id]}
        onChange={() => dispatch(setCheckboxAction(daily.id))}
      />            
      <label className="dailyName" htmlFor={daily.id}>
        <h4 className="dailyName">{dailyName.toUpperCase()}</h4>
      </label>
      <h4 className="deleteDailyBTN" onClick={() => deleteDaily(id)}>
        &#10005;
      </h4>
    </div>
  );
};
```